# How to add JavaScript array into localStorage for temporary data store?

Tags: javascript

I want to add my array data into `localStorage` so that when I enter data into a questions array my data should be there after refreshing the web page. Actually, I want to push questions array and store data into an array. Below code, I have tried but it's not working properly. Can anybody help me, please?

```
//add newly entered data into questions using localStorage.
  if(localStorage.getItem('setQuestions') == null){
    var questions =[];
}else{
    questions =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('setQuestions'));

}
```

Comment: What part isn't working?  Also, your redeclaring your questions variable.

Comment: @StevenB. I am unable to store new data into questions array using localStorage. The reason why I am using localStorage because when I refresh page the data that I have entered using form into questions array gone.

Comment: @StevenB. So, I want localStorage to keep data into questions array that I have entered using form input.

Comment: @StevenB.Or if there is another way to keep form input data into an array when we refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

First I should say localstorage is a key-value database; so you have to stringify your array by using `JSON.stringify(questions);` to convert an object/array to string;

It's very easily to add a string to localstorage :

```
localstorage.setItem("questions", JSON.stringify(questions));
```

But I recommend you to use **WebSQL** or **IndexedDb**

Comment: Acctually you just have to return an object insted of Question

Answer (score 0):

Just add data to an array, put it in the form of string via `JSON.stringify(questionss)` and then parse it. Then loop over it to get values.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('setQuestions') == null) {
  let questionss = [{
    question: "Why the grass is green?",
    answer: "Because of cholorophyll",
  }, {
    question: "What's the fastest made object on earth?",
    answer: "A man hole cover"
  }];
  localStorage.setItem("setQuestions", JSON.stringify(questionss));

} else {
  let questions = localStorage.getItem('setQuestions');

  JSON.parse(questions).forEach((val, index) =>  alert(val.question + " " + val.answer));
}
```

Check this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n84bdhsq/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Actually, you didn't show us where you stored the data prior to browser refresh. *Your data don't get stored automatically* :)

```
//As soon as you get your question array, do the following
var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
localStorage.setItem('setQuestions', dataToStore);

//And when you're back from movie and wish to continue, then do...
var questions = [];
var storedData = localStorage.getItem('setQuestions');
//Check if it was saved...
if(storedData) {
    questions = JSON.parse(storedData);
}
//You have the same array data that was stored. Now, call your girlfriend and tell her you just won a lotto. 8)
//Additionally, you mentioned `push` somewhere...
//If you need to add new questions to the old one, just do...
var extendedQuestions = questions.concat(newQuestions);/*newQuestions must be an array*/

/*
//add newly entered data into questions using localStorage.
if(localStorage.getItem('setQuestions') == null){
    var questions =[];
}else{
    questions =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('setQuestions'));
}
*/
```

**NOTE**
There's no real deal in asking someone to write your code for you or writing someone's code for them. We should learn how to do it on our own.

Answer (score -1):

`localstorage` accepts strings so simply `JSON.stringify` prior to storing and `JSON.parse` to read that string into an array object.

Comment: I did. That's what the back ticks signify in markdown, `code`.